# mdpi image is too small for 10" android tablet

Tags: android, android-layout, screen, drawable

I have drawables for each density as ldpi,mdpi,hdpi and xhdpi.

**Problem:** 
Both 10" tablet device (1280x800) and a handset device 320x480 uses medium density. I have an 35x35 mdpi image. But this image is too small for tablet whereas it is ok for handset.

I read relevant documents. But I guess I couldn't understand sth significant. Is there anyway for tablet use xhdpi images or I wonder how to use bigger images for mdpi tablet.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You should add a second identifier `large` and/or `xlarge` to your drawable folders. Increase the size in `drawable-xlarge-mdpi` until you are happy with the result while the `drawable-mdpi` will be the same size as before.

This increases the app size, but it will fix your issue.

Comment: @ warrenfaith : I have represented too with the same meaning.

Comment: @Raman-Mystry sorry, I don't understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: @WarrenFaith I tried your approach, that worked for me. Thanks. But because of the app size, I guess I will use kingraam's approach.

Comment: @WarrenFaith my last decision is to use this approach.

Comment: This solution works, but what about redundancy?! i have to ?DUPLICATE? all my drawable-?dpi folders to drawable-?large-?dpi many times, once per size per density... i cannot believe there isn't a "use that folder" way!! BTW, i won't try kingraam's solution because i have about 150 different icons!

Comment: The identifier large, xlarge etc are not recommended anymore. You should check the sw???dp identifier in the documentation.

Comment: Could you provide a link showing it's not recommended anymore; I can't find it and the docs still have the modifiers without warning. Thanks.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseSWQuali it might not be deprecated but the first few sentences will tell you why you should use the sw???dp identifiers instead of large etc.

Comment: I see that you should use sw(N)dp instead of size qualifier but wont developers still have to have a ton of drawable folders? Doesnt this mean I need the following drawable folders: sw340dp-mdpi, sw340dp-hdpi, sw340dp-xhdpi, sw480dp-mdpi, sw480dp-hdpi, sw480dp-xhdpi, sw600dp-mdpi, sw600dp-hdpi, sw600dp-xhdpi, sw720dp-mdpi, sw720dp-hdoi, sw720dp-xhdpi, sw800dp-mdpi, sw800dp-hdpi, & sw800dp-xhdpi?  Wouldn't you QUICKLY blow pasy the 50mb apk max size? What am I missing...?

Comment: @WarrenFaith, I used different resolution images for mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi,xxhdpi,xxxhdpi but still image on tabs is too small compared to that on phones.
kindly help.

Answer (score 18):

If you want to achieve this without increasing your app size, there is a way to let a high density screen and a large medium density screen use the same resource. You need to place the image you want to re-use in the 'drawable-nodpi' folder. This will stop the platform performing its own scaling when using it. For example, assuming you have a resource called 'my_resource', if you want the tablet-size screen to use your xhdpi resource, then move it out of drawable-xhdpi and rename it like this:

```
/drawable-nodpi/my_resource_xhdpi.png
```

Then in both the drawable-xhdpi and drawable-xlarge folders, create a file called my_resource.xml which looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/my_resource_xhdpi">
</bitmap>
```

Now when you use @drawable/my_resource, the xhdpi version will be used by xhdpi screens and xlarge screens, and you only have to maintain one version of the image. I use this technique quite a lot and it works really well. Hope that helps!

Comment: Yep you'll need one xml file like that per image, per density/screen size you want to use it. The downside of this approach is you have to cover more size/density combinations. For example if an hpdi tablet was released, you'd need to put an image or xml file in drawable-xlarge-hdpi, otherwise it will just use the one in drawable-xlarge which points to the image in drawable-nodpi.. and because it's in nodpi it wont be scaled up, so it will be physically smaller on screen. So use with care! I don't know of a better approach to share images between density and size folders though.

Comment: @kingraam My last decision is to use WarrenFaith's approach. App size is ~ 3mb and I think it is acceptable. Thanks for your workaround. I may use this workaround for other projects.

Answer (score 11):

These are defined as common practice:

Devices:

```
drawable-ldpi/xyz.png          low resolution devices 320x240 (now a days no phone comes with this resolution)
drawable-mdpi/xyz.png          medium resolution devices 480x320
drawable-hdpi/xyz.png          high resolution devices 800x480
drawable-xhdpi/xyz.png         Extra high resolution devices 1280*720
drawable-xxhdpi/xyz.png        Extra Extra high resolution devices 1920x1080
```

Tablets:

```
drawable-large-mdpi/xyz.png    7” Tablet (600x1024 mdpi)
drawable-xlarge-mdpi/xyz.png   10” tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc).
```

Answer (score 0):

I include some resources in drawable-xlarge, and drawable-large folders, in addition to the drawable-hdpi folders.  This works for me.

Another alternative, is to scale an image in code directly, which I do with the following code:

```
Drawable scaledIcon = new BitmapDrawable(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(myImage, pxInt, pxInt, true));
myImageView.setBackgroundDrawable(scaledIcon);
```

It is not a good idea to scale a lot of images in your code (using this method), as I think it is resource intensive to modify the images on the fly like this.  I do use this in some cases, where the image I am using may not be a standard size (and I want it to fit right always).