# android Imageview shows images too small on tablet despite given hdpi, xhdpi and xxhdpi, mdpi sizes

Tags: android, android-imageview

```
<ImageView
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout:height="wrap_content"
android:src="@drawable/someimage"
android:scaletype="fitxy"
/>
```

Why the image is too small on the screen than expected? How do we scale the image to the real size. The image size is much larger than what is showing up on android screen. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please post the screen shot.

Comment: Also post the full layout, the parent layout may be restricting the size of the child view.

Comment: Are all the images created at the standard **72 dpi** resolution or do you respect the correct image resolutions per screen density?

Comment: possible duplicate of [mdpi image is too small for 10" android tablet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926534/mdpi-image-is-too-small-for-10-android-tablet)