# What to do when MDPI image is too small on tablets while perfect on devices?

Tags: android-layout

An image is placed into `/drawable-mdpi` directory and by Google docs it should cover all MDPI devices, both mobiles and tablets. However, it is perfect on MDPI mobile device, while it's too small on tablets. This is true if I keep images height and width to `wrap_content`.

If I try to play with widget width or height, it's not only the wrong approach, but images becomes blurry as their size has been increased.

I have browsed Google open source apps on Github and saw that **neither of them has special images for MDPI tablets**. So there is no `/drawable-(x)large-mdpi` resources at all. Also in Android docs, Google discourages creating too many resource directories but rather stick to general ones only (`/drawable-{mdpi/hdpi/xhdpi/...}`.

Having all this in mind, what IS the proper way to handle small images?

And by all means, I want to avoid using any `dpi` values.

**NOTE:** I have read [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926534/mdpi-image-is-too-small-for-10-android-tablet?rq=1) on SO before posting the question, but this one proposes creation of new resource folders, which Google discourages.

Comment: There are special layout/values/drawables folders for tablets. Most of  the times you can build the folder name by knowing the minimum width or heigth in dp or the resolution in px

Comment: @DerGolem I am interested in `drawable` in this question. I am aware of other suffixes to "drawable" word. But my concern is raised because Google has special policy for drawables, unlike for layouts or values.

Comment: `Google has special policy for drawables`?? So, is this: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#NewQualifiers pure bullshit?

Comment: @DerGolem My point exactly. Try to find any qualifier like `drawable-SCREEN_SIZE-DPI_VALUE`. You can't. They always refer to layout or values when they have to set something like `layout-large-mdpi` or `value-xlarge-mdpi`. They follow the same logic in their open source projects and never create anything like `drawable-large-mdpi`. Why? Don't know and that is why I am asking how they handle such small MDPI images on tablets.

Comment: hmmm. I see. It seems there is some lack in the drawable namings.

Comment: @DerGolem Yes, and not just a "lack". They use such convention in their projects. They add suffixes to all resource folders, but never to `drawable`. To clarify, I also added suffixes like you suggested in the past, but when I saw how Google guys do, I asked myself why I did it in such a way when it seems to be the wrong way.

Comment: `it seems to be the wrong way` ... does it work? it's the correct way. If it doesn't, you should start to worry about.